# grep and replace multiple strings between multiple files

Tags: regex, scripting, sed, grep

I have multiple XML files with strings that are all set to

```
<msg type="Status"
```

Some of these strings should be type "Warning" and I have a separate text file with the warning strings.

I can do a

> grep -f strings.txt *.xml

this allows me to see which warning strings are incorrectly listed as status strings. What I would like to do is

> grep -f strings.txt *.xml | sed 's/status/warning/'

This gives me my desired output, but it is only being displayed (not saved). There are multiple xml files so i can't just save the output to one file. I need sed to replace the string in the original .xml file it originated from. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any reason you're not using [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) to parse the file?

Comment: Probably just ignorance, i'm just working with what I know.

Comment: It'll save you a lot of grief - you can pass multiple xml files and use the `--pattern` option to use xpath to search it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you were close instead of `grep -f strings.txt *.xml | sed 's/status/warning/'`

do

```
grep -l strings.txt *.xml | xargs sed -i 's/status/warning/g'
```

you forgot to use `xargs`, read [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-xargs-construct-argument-lists-utility/) for more info about `xargs`.

Comment: only using -rl doesn't produce anything, sorry for all the questions

Comment: run this command:

`grep -l strings.txt *.xml | xargs sed -i 's/status/warning/g'` I fixed it.

Comment: If it do `grep -f strings.txt *.xml` i see all my shared lines. If i `grep -l strings.txt *.xml` I don't get any output. Thanks for all the troubleshooting help.

Comment: Specifically I see something like this `vnlrmsg.xml:<msg type="Status" text="$$s$$s was previously declared with a different range. (VNLR-1050)" uid="1050"/>`

Comment: so do `grep -fl strings.txt *.xml |xargs sed -i 's/status/warning/g';` otherwise I don't know what you are using.

Comment: In the end it worked. I'm using cygwin on this box and I had to use `dos2unix` on my files for everything to work correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend trying [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html). Using the `--pattern` option, you can specify xpath search queries to search for exactly what you need it to find without complicated regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks, i'm looking up its usage now. Hopefully it does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Perl script xml_grep using xpath as query language:
http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/tools/xml_grep/xml_grep

```
xml_grep '//msg[@type="Warning"]' *.xml
```